# Why I am not able to get Spore move on my Shroomish?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I play Pokemon Sapphire using MyBoy emulator on Android. My friends and I battle and trade Pokemon, so I decided what get Sporeloom Combo for me.
This is what I did:

- First I searched on net and got that only some Pokémon learns Spore such as Shroomish/Paras/Parasect etc
- So I traded Paras (Male) with Spore move from Leaf Green to Sapphire.
- Then I bred it with Shroomish (Female) in Day care Center in Mauvile.
- But after hatching eggs none of my Shroomish seems to get Spore move .I hatched 5 eggs and then stopped.

What I am doing something wrong? Any other way to get spore on Shroomish? 
I want Shroomish to learn Spore to evolve it into Breloom so that my Breloom have Spore learnt.

Comment: Did the Shroomish you hatched have a full set of moves? Or were there empty slots?

Comment: @Angzuril 2 empty slots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breloom does not learn Spore.

As seen on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Breloom_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#By_a_prior_evolution), he can only acquire Spore as a Shroomish (prior evolution).

Your breeding does not work because [Spore is not an Egg move for Shroomish](http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/shroomish/egg).

In Generation 3 [Shroomish learns Spore at level 54](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shroomish_(Pok%C3%A9mon)/Generation_III_learnset#By_leveling_up)

You can breed a Shroomish with Spore, but both parents must already know Spore (because it is a level up move). [Bulbapedia on passing moves down.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_breeding#Passing_moves_down)

> If **both parents** know a move that the baby can **learn via leveling up**, the Pokémon will inherit that move.